# React Redux not changing props when page already loaded

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga, rerender

We're working with a simple loading overlay.
We take the location change in the sagas, and working like this:

```
export function* handleLocationChange() {
  while (true) { 
    yield take(LOCATION_CHANGE);
    yield put({type: LOADING_PAGE})
  }
}
```

In our different types of layouts, we stop the 'loader state' by dispathing a 'HIDE_LOADING_PAGE', as we can see:

```
class Layout extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super();
    props.hideLoadingBar();
  }  
  (...)
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  hideLoadingBar: url => dispatch({ type: HIDE_LOADING_PAGE}),
});
```

The code for the LoadingBar is the following:

```
class LoadingBar extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super();
    this.state = {loader: false};
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.setState({loader: this.props.loader});
  }

  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps){
    // when already rendered before, props stay unchanged.

  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  loader: getLoaderState(state), //asks for a 'loader'/'show' key
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(LoadingBar);
```

Reducer:

```
function commonLoaderReducer(state = initialState, { id, index, type, data, error, resultKey }) {

  switch (type) {
    case LOADING_PAGE:
      return state.set("show", true );
    case HIDE_LOADING_PAGE:
      return state.set("show", false );
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

The first time we try it, and we go from page A to page B, it works perfectly. The loading page shows and hides as the redux state changes.

But if we go from page B to page A again, the loader is not shown. I can see in redux how the actions are both dispatched (LOADING_PAGE and HIDE_LOADING_PAGE) but in the shouldUpdateComponents(nextProps), the nextProps stay the same. They never change as they should.

Any clues??

Edit: We're using immutable for redux's state, and LOCATION_CHANGE is react-router-redux's

Comment: Have you tried using the spread operator instead of `state.set`? I have't seen it used in reducers before, not sure if its mutating the sate. Try `return {...state, 'show': false}` etc.

Comment: That's because she is using immutable

Comment: why not use `componentDidUpdate()` and also check for `prevProps`?